# Script to replace user permissions?

Tags: windows, permissions, unix, scripting

I am moving resources from Mac and Unix boxes onto our windows storage server. I need to replicate permissions from Mac and Unix using the users active directory equivalent.

So:

File A On Location A With Permissions A

to

File A On Location B With Permissions B

Permission B is the active directory equivalent of the ldap permissions on unix.

Any idea on how I should go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install Samba, which understands both unix & windows permissions.  The next step would be to get the owenerships/permissions syncronized to they way that you want them to be on the AD/Windows side.  Next, you could then use something like robocopy or xxcopy to transfer the files via the samba share to their final destination.  These programs have the capability of retaining file ownership & permissions while copying files (and timestamps).

Comment: I copy using xcopy, and robocopy xcopy throws errors and robocopy does not keep permissions when they are copied.

Comment: Okay robocopy I followed: http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2008/07/31/robocopy-mir-switch-mirroring-file-permissions.aspx seems to have transferred permissions now I just need to map windows ad users to the correct ldap user permissions.